# minimization does not proceed as expected in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have been learning tensorflow 2.0 these days. I wrote a very simple model for testing. Specifically, I want to minimize the function x1^2-2x1+1, which reaches the optimal when x1 = 1. Instead of creating only one variable x1, I created any other variable x2 = 2x1 + 1 to see does it work if I have complicated relationships between different variables in the future.
Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

var1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1]))
var2 = tf.add(tf.multiply(-2, var1), 1)

loss = lambda: var1 * var1 + var2

for i in range(1000):
    opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[var1])
    print('var1: {}, var2: {}'.format(var1.numpy(), var2.numpy()))
```

variable var1 quickly converges to 0, while var2 remain unchanged. So, where is the problem in my code?

Comment: do you need `var_list=[var1,var2]`?  var2 appears to be missing 
 https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#minimize

Comment: @Stanton Adding var2 to the var_list will raise an error: NotImplementedError("Trying to update a Tensor ", var). That makes sense since var1 is the only independent variable which can be optimized.

Comment: I haven't played with TF2.  Perhaps you need to `var2.eval().numpy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are writing code as if you were in graph mode (TF 1.x). When you write the line:

```
var2 = tf.add(tf.multiply(-2, var1), 1)
```

`var2` will be assigned a value (the initial random value of `var1` times two plus one), and then it does not change anymore. Unlike in graph mode, where `var2` would represent the symbolic computation `-2 * var1 + 1`, in eager mode it is just a value computed at the time that line of code is evaluated. This means that your loss function is really just computing `var1` squared plus some constant, so the minimum is always reached when `var1` equals zero.

In TF 2.x you have to do the computation of the loss on each training iteration, instead of expressing it symbolically once before the training loop as in TF 1.x. So, the computation of `var2` would have to be done within the `loss` function, for every new value of `var1`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
var1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1]))
def loss():
    var2 = tf.add(tf.multiply(-2, var1), 1)
    return var1 * var1 + var2

for i in range(1000):
    opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[var1])
    print('var1: {}'.format(var1.numpy()))
    # ...
    # var1: [0.9999999]
```